# AIR for IOS publish settings vs AIR for IOS Settings

Tags: air, gpu

Can anyone tell me what the relationship is between the 'hardware acceleration' option in Publish settings and the 'Render mode' in AIR for iOS settings.

Does one override the other?
In both you can set GPU or Direct so its somewhat confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render mode in Publish Settings is for Flash files played in a web page. The render mode value is not embedded in a swf – it's set in the containing HTML/JavaScript.

Setting a render mode in Publish Settings would have no effect on an AIR file.